Rank sums and combinatorics
I had (and probably still have) some confusion about rank sums, so I apologize if this question takes a tint of this confusion with it.
Say we have a labeling function $x:\{1,\ldots,n\}\to\{0,1\}$ and $M(x):=\{(i,j) |\, i<j \land (i,j)\in x^{-1}(0)\times x^{-1}(1)\}$ and $J(x):=|M(x)|.$
Part of my confusion is that I remember the above $J$ as rank sum, which obviously is a different thing but it looks like there is a one to one mapping. I created a (private) proof of this, but being out of practice for really a far too long time, I don't trust my proof, and it involves cumbersome notations so it is not easy to reproduce it here.
Minor question: what is the name for the above function $J$?
Major question: is there a correspondence of $J$ with the rank sum, and if so, what is it and where can I read a proof of that?

The relation is (notations from my cumbersome proof) that $$\forall_x\;J(x)+r(x)=n_1(x)n_0(x) + \dfrac{n_1(x)(n_1(x)+1)}2$$
where $n_1$ and $n_0$ is the number of elements in $x^{-1}(1)$ and $x^{-1}(0)$ respectively, and $r(x)$ is the rank sum with respect to $1$.

Is that true, and known, or just a bug in my mind?
